# How to convert an English string of a number into a float (e.g. "twenty-six"=>26.0)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, nlp

I'm building a chatbot and I want to be able to parse strings representing numerical amounts that represent a human age. When I ask `"How old are you?"` the user should be able to input `"26"` or `"twenty-six"` and have the bot understand it as `26.0`. The method should handle converting fractions to decimals.

Examples:

```
parse("six")              # => 6.0
parse("twenty-five")      # => 25.0
parse("three and a half") # => 3.5
```

Is there a gem that handles this in Ruby already, or is it easy enough to write a simple `parse` method?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I'm building a chat bot and I want to be able to parse out numeric responses. For example, I ask `"How old are you?"` and the user may say  `"26"` or `"twenty-six"` and I the bot to understand it as `26.0`

Comment: or just use a splitting dictionary

Comment: "one" - > 1;   
"two" - > 2;   
.....

Comment: then when a number is greater than hundred just append two zeros; for example: "one hundred" will return 1 (because of the dictionary matching), and the +"00" because we replace a "hundred" with two zeros... which will return 100

Comment: What would be some sample input for say... 126?

Comment: I would suggest using a lexer/parser for this. I would recommend [Ruby Language Tool kit](https://github.com/chriswailes/RLTK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution that just looks for number words in the input string and adds them together. This works in English for ages < 100.

```
def parse(string)
  dict = {
    half: 0.5, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4,
    five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9,
    ten: 10, eleven: 11, twelve: 12, thirteen: 13,
    fourteen: 14, fifteen: 15, sixteen: 16,
    seventeen: 17, eighteen: 18, nineteen: 19,
    twenty: 20, thirty: 30, forty: 40, fifty: 50,
    sixty: 60, seventy: 70, eighty: 80, ninety: 90
  }

  age = 0.0

  dict.each do |s, n|
    # Scans string for each number name, adding numeric value if found
    age += n if string[/\b#{s}\b/]
  end

  return age
end

parse "six"              # => 6.0
parse "twenty-five"      # => 25.0
parse "three and a half" # => 3.5
parse "four and twenty"  # => 24.0
```

Comment: Great answer! Totally outshines mine, i'm deleting it! +1. I think that you could improve your answer with some comments saying how it works step by step though. Definitely would help me with my learning.

Comment: Use `inject` instead of `each` as that don't have any side-effects.